# State and prove a theorem that gives a relationship between κ(G) and c(G) for a graph G of order n.

Tags: graph-theory

The connection number c(G) of a connected graph G of order n ≥ 2 is
the smallest integer k with 2 ≤ k ≤ n such that every induced subgraph
of order k in G is connected. State and prove a theorem that gives a
relationship between κ(G) and c(G) for a graph G of order n.

I honestly don't know where to start here. Obviously if c(G)=2 the graph is complete and k(G)=n-1, but I don't know where to go with that or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: When c(G)=3 you get "line graphs" for every order-3 subragraph. What happens when c(G)=4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every subgraph with $c$ vertices is connected, that's the same as removing $n-c$ vertices always leaving the graph connected. And the existence of a disconnected subgraph with $c-1$ vertices is the same as it being possible to remove $n-c+1$ vertices and leave a connected graph. So $\kappa (G) + c(G) = n + 1$.